# URL Request not working in android Request.Method.POST?

Tags: java, php, android, node.js, json

Trying to send a URL request using this, but not working....
URL is -https://example.site/sendotp?otp="+randonnumber+"&number="+phoneNumber
(line number 514,509 ref added)

```
    void sendotp(String phoneNumber){
    Random random = new Random();
    randonnumber=random.nextInt(999999);
    try {
        if (new ExtraOperations().haveNetworkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
       [509]StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://example.site/sendotp?otp="+randonnumber+"&number="+phoneNumber, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                   [514]JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                        String success = jsonObject1.getString("success");

                        if (success.equals("1")) {

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
```

logcat error is this.. don't know what is this or how to fix...

```
2020-08-28 21:42:46.682 1844-27397/? I//system/bin/netd: gethostby*.getanswer: asked for "blitzplay.in IN AAAA", got type "RRSIG"
2020-08-28 21:42:46.683 1844-27397/? I//system/bin/netd: gethostby*.getanswer: asked for "blitzplay.in IN A", got type "RRSIG"
2020-08-28 21:42:48.352 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value ERR of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2020-08-28 21:42:48.352 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at com.blitzplay.in.activity.OTPActivity$13.onResponse(OTPActivity.java:514)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at com.blitzplay.in.activity.OTPActivity$13.onResponse(OTPActivity.java:509)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.353 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.354 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.354 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2020-08-28 21:42:48.354 27123-27123/com.blitzplay.in W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: It seems that the String `response` you get on the `onResponse` method cannot be converted to a JSONObject. Try logging your response String to check what's the problem with that `Log.d("TAG", "response: " + response);`

Comment: Log.d("TAG", "response: " + response); is not returning any information in logcat

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, (was an issue with a number input)